# Suppose $f:[a,b] \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ is bounded.Let $A(g)=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}g(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Suppose $f:[a,b] \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ is bounded.Let $A(g)=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}g(x)dx$ for any bounded function $g:[a,b] \rightarrow [0,\infty)$.Show that $A(f)^2 \le A(f^2)$.

I was thinking of using MVT for integrals.But it is not quite helping

Comment: I think CS inequality for integrals might be helpful here

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Use of course Cauchy Schwarz !

$$\int_a^b g(x)=\int_a^b 1\cdot g(x)dx\underset{C.S.}{\leq}\sqrt{\int_a^b dx}\sqrt{\int_a^b g^2(x)dx}$$